# Why does this inline svg look rasterized on Android?

Tags: android, svg

This has been driving me up the wall all day today. I'm generating an inline svg chart which looks like a low-res image on my Android 4.3.1 but only in certain cases.

Every svg image i find online looks fine every time. But every time I make a plain html page with any of these svgs (copied and pasted), they look rasterized. Firefox for Android looks fine every time, Chrome for Android looks fine every time, but the stock browser screws it up. iOS Safari is fine also.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="chart" width="320px" height="100px"><desc>Created with Snap</desc><defs></defs><path d="M40 70L53 70L67 70L80 70L93 69L107 68L120 69L133 60L147 55L160 60L173 54L187 42L200 21L213 23" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0)" stroke="#ffff00" style="stroke-width: 1;"></path><path d="M40 36L53 36L67 36L80 36L93 38L107 41L120 35L133 40L147 34L160 37L173 37L187 37L200 50L213 48" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0)" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="1"></path></svg>
```

here it works, try zooming in on the result.
http://jsfiddle.net/9jxvx/light/

but on full-screen result page it doesn't:
http://jsfiddle.net/9jxvx/embedded/result/

Comment: Just a guess, but the stock browser may be caching the rendered SVG as a bitmap, and not regenerating it when you zoom.  Possibly for speed reasons.

Comment: Have you tried using a `viewBox` attribute with this, possibly removing the width and height attributes at the same time?